# addition of specific elements of a list python

Tags: python, list

A "pyschool" exercise :

> "Define a function calls `addFirstAndLast(x)` that takes in a list of numbers and returns the sum of the first and last numbers."

Here is the best solution I have come up with. Is there a more elegant way to write this function that also only uses only built in functions?

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):
    sum_list = []
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(x) == 1 :
        return int(x[0])
    elif len(x) > 1 :
        sum_list.append(x[0]) 
        sum_list.append(x[-1])
    return sum(sum_list)
```

Comment: `return x[0] + x[-1]` for the last case, There is no need to create a new list as `sum_list` and then apply `sum()` if you really have only 2 numbers to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def addFirstAndLast(x):
...   return (x[0]+x[-1])/(1/len(x)+1) if x else 0
... 
>>> addFirstAndLast([])
0
>>> addFirstAndLast([1])
1
>>> addFirstAndLast([1,3])
4
```

*Note 1* : only when the length of list is 1 the result of `(1/len(x)+1)` is 2 so you divide the sum of first and last elements by 2 else it divide by 1.

*Note 2* : if you are in python 3 use `//` for division instead `/`.

Comment: This handles all the test cases., great :)

Comment: Somewhat convoluted logic there... and shouldn't you be using `//` for integer division?

Comment: @PM2Ring In python 3 yes but in this case there is no need to that because OP has **accepted** the answer!

Comment: Answers on Stack Exchange sites are also for the benefit of future readers, not just the OP.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes its true :)

Answer (score 2):

Kasra's answer is a lot better but this is a slightly different way to go about it. Since `x[0]` is always returned if it exists, you can just check if `x[-1]` should be added too.

```
def firstAndLast(x):
    if x:
        value = x[0]
        if len(x)>1:
            value += x[-1]
        return value
    return 0
```

Comment: Your code is easier to understand than Kasra's, and doesn't perform 2 mysterious divisions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):
    if x:
        return sum(zip(*filter(lambda (i,s): i == 0 or i == len(x) - 1, enumerate(x)))[1])
    else:
        return 0
```

Enumerate elements in the list, filter, unzip and then return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Use extended slice notation, with `max` to handle an empty list.

```
for i in range(5):
    a = range(10, 10 + i)
    b = a[::max(1, len(a)-1)]
    print a, b, sum(b)
```

**output**

```
[] [] 0
[10] [10] 10
[10, 11] [10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] [10, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] [10, 13] 23
```

---

And here's a version that does it in a function.

```
def add_first_and_last(x):
    return sum(x[::max(1, len(x)-1)])

for i in range(5):
    a = range(10, 10 + i)
    print a, add_first_and_last(a)
```

**output**

```
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
```

---

At Kasra's prompting I've done some timing tests of the main existing answers. I've also added a modified version of Peter's algorithm that's *slightly* faster.

```
from timeit import Timer

def addFirstAndLast_Sam(x):
    sum_list = []
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(x) == 1 :
        return int(x[0])
    elif len(x) > 1 :
        sum_list.append(x[0]) 
        sum_list.append(x[-1])
    return sum(sum_list)

def add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_slow(x):
    return sum(x[::max(1, len(x)-1)])

def add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_fast(x):
    return x[0] + x[-1] if len(x) > 1 else x[0] if x else 0

def firstAndLast_Peter(x):
    if x:
        value = x[0]
        if len(x)>1:
            value += x[-1]
        return value
    return 0

def addFirstAndLast_Kasra(x):
    return (x[0] + x[-1]) // (1 // len(x) + 1) if x else 0

funcs = (
    add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_fast,
    firstAndLast_Peter,
    addFirstAndLast_Kasra,
    add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_slow,
    addFirstAndLast_Sam,
)

num = 10
lists = [range(10, 10 + i) for i in range(num + 1)]

def verify():
    ''' Verify that the functions actually perform as intended '''
    print 'Verifying...'
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.func_name
        print '\n%s' % fname
        for a in lists:
            print a, func(a)

def time_test(loops, reps):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    print '\nTiming tests\nLoops = %d, Repetitions = %d' % (loops, reps)

    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.func_name
        print '\n%s' % fname
        setup = 'from __main__ import lists, %s' % fname
        t = Timer('[%s(a) for a in lists]' % fname, setup)
        r = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        r.sort()
        print r

verify()
time_test(loops=10000, reps=3)
```

**output**

```
Verifying...

add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_fast
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 24
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 26
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] 27
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 28
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 29

firstAndLast_Peter
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 24
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 26
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] 27
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 28
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 29

addFirstAndLast_Kasra
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 24
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 26
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] 27
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 28
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 29

add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_slow
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 24
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 26
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] 27
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 28
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 29

addFirstAndLast_Sam
[] 0
[10] 10
[10, 11] 21
[10, 11, 12] 22
[10, 11, 12, 13] 23
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 24
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 26
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] 27
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] 28
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] 29

Timing tests
Loops = 10000, Repetitions = 3

add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_fast
[0.15383195877075195, 0.15486502647399902, 0.18578314781188965]

firstAndLast_Peter
[0.16625690460205078, 0.16726803779602051, 0.17240190505981445]

addFirstAndLast_Kasra
[0.19242000579833984, 0.19251012802124023, 0.21216797828674316]

add_first_and_last_PM2Ring_slow
[0.38388991355895996, 0.39070892333984375, 0.39607501029968262]

addFirstAndLast_Sam
[0.38914084434509277, 0.38966894149780273, 0.41235685348510742]
```

As you can see, my original code is definitely *not* the fastest, but it *is* the shortest. :)

Comment: There is no need to use  `sum` and `max` and `len` for this simple task!!! you just make it very inefficient!

Comment: @Kasra: I agree that this approach is slower than yours. OTOH, Peter's code is faster than both of ours. I'll post some timing tests.